# Is there a way to set Hive configurations using Hive magic in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: hadoop, hive, jupyter-notebook, hive-configuration

I am using Jupyter Notebook to crunch data in Hive and I want to set Hive configurations using Hive magic. Is there a way to do it?

Sample code below does not work (Please treat them as one Jupyter Notebook cell each block). I can do this via HUE but I find it better to do in Jupyter Notebook because I can add some notes via Markdown.

```
%%hive
set hive.cbo.enable=false
```

```
%%hive

select *
from some_table
```

Comment: I assume you are asking if there is a Hive magic function library for IPython? Hue is not the same as Jupyter/IPython. HUE also supports Markdown cells, last I checked, or you can use Zeppelin `%sql` interpreter with Hive.